# How to deactivate Kendo UI Drawer for certain #div (and use GMaps)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I need to use a map and some content in within the same view. On the forums they advice to move the map to a separate page but I need to implement it for UX reason.

So I'd like to build a function that disable the drawer when the user scroll the map in different direction (and so, use the map native scrolling function) and enable it when its anywhere else on the page.

I have no clue where to start, I'm not (yet!) a JS ninja and dealing with telerik source code is not easy ( or at least their complete API )

Where should I start ? Is it even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for the same answer, you have to use e.stopPropagation()

```
$( "#gmap" ).on( "mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
    Map.setDragFlag(true);
});
```